# Remove space from the end of each line of output (Python)

Tags: python

```
n = int(input("Size: "))
for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print('\r')
print(0)
```

This code is totally okay but prints whitespace with end of each line in the output.

Comment: `print(j, end=' ' if j < i else '')`

Comment: no, it removes all spaces. I need the spaces between the numbers, but don't need the one in the end.

Comment: Can you show **exactly** what the output should be for some sample input

Comment: There is whitespace at the end of each line in the output. I don't need those spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you did it like this:

```
n = int(input("Size: "))
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    print(*range(i))
```

**Output:**

```
Size: 5
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
0 1 2
0 1
0
```

There will be no trailing whitespace characters if you do this

Comment: Now, there is a extra whiteline after 0

Comment: Your output looks correct apart from having an extra new line.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
n =int(input("Size: "))
for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print(j, end=' ') if j<i else print(j, end='')
    print('\r')
print(0)
```